# Bootable USB is listed in UEFI settings but not boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04. I want to enlarge my ubuntu partition so I created a bootable USB with ubuntu 22.04 on it, since apparently that's what you need to do. However, the USB doesn't show up in the boot menu. However, when I select 'UEFI settings' in the boot menu it is listed in the options for setting the boot order.

Also, I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I tried resetting the UEFI to factory settings to solve this problem, and that got rid of the UEFI menu and took me to windows automatically when I turned the computer on. I got the boot menu back by going into window's command prompt and typing in "bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi" Now when I start my computer it says something like "path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi not found" but then the boot menu loads anyway.

Comment: Resetting UEFI, returns it to defaults. You have to go back and change any settings you originally did to install Ubuntu. USB or any external device boots from the device, not an "ubuntu" entry. It should be UEFI:xxx where xxx is name or label of flash drive. What brand/model system. Some like HP require you to change boot order in UEFI setting, not UEFI boot menu.

Comment: I know that it returns to defaults, but the point is that the problem existed even before I reset the UEFI.